# How to set two timeouts?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am trying to have two separate timeout times in my coursel (so that 2 slides are faster than the others). I have all of my images at 7 seconds but I want my "brands1slide" and "brands2slide" to be 3.5 seconds.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 7000);
}
```

```html
<div class="SlidesDiv" style="max-width:1024px">
  <img class="mySlides" id="returnsSlide" alt="returnsSlide" src="img/ReturnsOnly.png" />
  <img class="mySlides" id="brands1Slide" alt="brands1Slide" src="img/Brands_1.png" />
  <img class="mySlides" id="brands2Slide" alt="brands2Slide" src="img/Brands_2.png" />
  <img class="mySlides" id="fsaSlide" alt="brands2Slide" src="img/FSAs.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: You don't want "two timeouts", you merely want to dynamically determine the necessary timeout value for the next `setTimeout` call. In pseudo code: `if (currentSlide == 'brands2slide') timeout = 3500 else timeout = 7000; setTimeout(carousel, timeout);` And the `if` condition should be fairly simple, even just using `slideIndex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to have an array of times specifying the timeout for each slide:

```
var slideTimes = [7000, 3500, 3500, 7000];
```

Then you can use that to choose a good timeout for each slide:

```
setTimeout(carousel, slideTimes[slideIndex - 1]);
```

Snippet:

```js
var slideTimes = [3500, 3500, 7000, 7000];
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, slideTimes[slideIndex - 1]);
}
```

```html
<div class="SlidesDiv" style="max-width:1024px">
  <img class="mySlides" id="returnsSlide" alt="returnsSlide" src="img/ReturnsOnly.png" />
  <img class="mySlides" id="brands1Slide" alt="brands1Slide" src="img/Brands_1.png" />
  <img class="mySlides" id="brands2Slide" alt="brands2Slide" src="img/Brands_2.png" />
  <img class="mySlides" id="fsaSlide" alt="brands2Slide" src="img/FSAs.png" />
</div>
```